# SGE qsub define variable using bach?

Tags: qsub

I am trying to automatically set up several variables for SGE system but get no luck.

```
#!/bin/bash

myname="test"
totaltask=10

#$ -N $myname
#$ -cwd
#$ -t 1-$totaltask
```

apparently $myname will not be recognized. any solution?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider making a wrapper function

qsub_file.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#$ -V
#$ -cwd
```

wrapper_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
myname="test"
totaltask=10
qsub qsub_script.sh -N ${myname} -t 1-${totaltask}
```

Comment: sorry i no longer use qsub... thanks a lot for the answers. I accept it and hope it will be useful information to others.